# Is it possible to install and distribute custom Keyman keyboards on Android devices without predictive text?

Tags: unicode, keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

Please pardon if my question is simple as I'm not a programmer nor anything like that (yet).  But, I've been experimenting with producing custom calligraphic and creative fonts for some years and have recently been using them with custom keyboards I've assembled as well.  A number of these are only semi-familiar and aren't in mainstream usage especially not how I might use some of them.  Thus, they aren't likely to have much text written in them to provide a predictive dictionary.

I have a number of other Keyman keyboards activated on my personal device, and I didn't notice predictive texts while using those.

So, how can I install my custom keyboards and font/s on an Android device and avoid having to include predictive texts?  I'll likely include predictive texts in other projects.  But, I'd like to just distribute and install a few keyboards and fonts without the dictionaries at this time.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard packages and lexical model (dictionary) packages are managed separately in Keyman. There is no requirement to build a lexical model for a language in order to use a keyboard for that language. So, building a keyboard package will not force you to also build a dictionary.

When you install a keyboard package from Keyman Cloud (via the Add Keyboard menu option in Keyman for Android), Keyman will look for a lexical model package that goes with it as well, and install it. For example, you may choose [sil_euro_latin.kmp](https://keyman.com/keyboards/sil_euro_latin) as an English (`en`) keyboard. Keyman would then find and install [nrc.en.mtnt.kmp](https://github.com/keymanapp/lexical-models/tree/master/release/nrc/nrc.en.mtnt) as an English lexical model. But if you install a custom keyboard, for a language that does not have a corresponding model available in Keyman Cloud, it will still work.

Note that fonts cannot be installed system-wide on Android devices. This is an Android limitation.

Comment: Thanks, Marc.  I'll try it out.  There's a possibility I could be overlooking something else as I'm new to this.  Thanks again.

Comment: At this point I'm getting the following message:

"Package
...
No keyboards or predictive text to install".

The package has: .kmx; .kvk; .kvks; .ttf; .ico; .keyman-touch-layout; -coad.js.

The Project features are:
Include Codes ...txt; Icon ...ico; Desktop On-Screen Keyboard ...kvks; Touch-Optimized Keyboard; Embedded JavaScript ...js.

Is there something I've left out and/or something I shouldn't have included?

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: You need: .kmx, .kvk, .ttf, .js (not -load.js), and optionally welcome.htm, readme.htm (plus any files those refer to). See https://help.keyman.com/developer/13.0/guides/distribute/packages; note that kmp.inf and kmp.json are included automatically.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  At this point, I just want to test distributing it a little first before I trouble myself with welcome.htm and readme.htm, etc...  I'm thinking that testing it like that first would help with the content of my commentary in additional documentation files I'd include with the package.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hello again.  I have: .kmx, .kvk, .js, .ttf, .ico.  But, I didn't remove: .kvks, -codes.txt, -code.js, keyman-touch-layout.  I'm thinking I should at least have the keyman-touch-layout in the package since I'm trying to install it on an Android.  But, I'm still getting the message "...No keyboards or predictive text to install".  So, is there something I should remove that's preventing it from installing?  Is there something else missing from the package I'm overlooking?

Comment: The .kvks, -codes.txt, -code.js, .keyman-touch-layout are all source files and not required for distribution. Check that the Keyboards tab is populated in your package source file -- you need to have at least 1 language code for the keyboard. You may find it easier also to continue this discussion at https://community.software.sil.org/c/keyman and share some of your source files there.